# How to add multiple identity and multiple role in asp.net core

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I am new to asp.net core. So this might not be a good question.

I have 3 classes: `Admin`, `Doctor`, `Patient`.

I want all those users to be able to login and see their dashboard. All of them will have different level of access.

So I derived these classes from `IdenetityUser` like this:

```
public class Admin : IdentityUser
{
}

public class Doctor : IdentityUser
{
    public const int MaxAppointPerDay = 28;

    public Gender Gender { get; set; }
}

public class Patient : IdentityUser
{
    public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }
    public Gender Gender { get; set; }
}
```

I am just stuck after this.

When I tried to add multiple Identitiy by the method `AddIdentity<TUser, TRole>()`, it gave me error.

What do I do next?

Most of the examples in the internet involves one `IdentityUser` and multiple `IdentityRole`. But since the user models are all different, I couldn't go that way.

Thank you.

Comment: You can extend your base identitymodel with multiple properties and manage access over the roles. I can recommend you, not create multiple tables for manage your users. This will make a lot of work for you and you can not using standard implementations. What will happen, if anyone would like to have a accesslevel for a nurse?

Comment: You cannot repeatedly use `AddIdentity` to add an identity.
ASP.NET Core provides a built-in method:`AddIdentityCore<TUser>`
You can use it like this: `services.AddIdentityCore<Admin>();`

Comment: @Yinqiu If I use `AddIdentityCore`, would I be able to add more than one Identity?

Comment: Yes,you can try it.

Comment: Hi @Muzib,any updates about this case?

Comment: @Yinqiu sorry for the late reply. Yes it works.

Comment: What it does is, it merges all the properties of all the added identities into one `AspNetUsers` table.

Comment: of course, do it

Comment: If this solves your problem, you can mark it as an answer, which will help people who encounter the same problem in the future.Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot repeatedly use `AddIdentity` to add an identity.

ASP.NET Core provides a built-in method:`AddIdentityCore<TUser>`.

You can use it like this: `services.AddIdentityCore<Admin>();`

**Edit:**

Adding to Yinqiu's answer, for the future readers, if you use this `AddIdentityCore` method, the `AspNetUsers` table will merge all the properties of each `IdentityUser`. Here is an example:

Let `Teacher` and `Student` are two `IdentityUser` and both of them have at least one distinct properties, like this:

```
public class Teacher : IdentityUser
{
    public string Subject { get; set; }
}

public class Student : IdentityUser
{
    public int Grade { get; set; }
}
```

Then I add both of their Identity in the `startup.cs` like this:

```
services.AddIdentityCore<Teacher>().AddEntityFrameworkStores<AppDbContext>();
services.AddIdentityCore<Student>().AddEntityFrameworkStores<AppDbContext>();
```

The *AspNetUsers* table will include both the `Subject` property and the `Grade` property. Here is the proof from migration class:

```
migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
    name: "AspNetUsers",
    columns: table => new
    {
        Id = table.Column<string>(nullable: false),
        UserName = table.Column<string>(maxLength: 256, nullable: true),
        NormalizedUserName = table.Column<string>(maxLength: 256, nullable: true),
        Email = table.Column<string>(maxLength: 256, nullable: true),
        NormalizedEmail = table.Column<string>(maxLength: 256, nullable: true),
        EmailConfirmed = table.Column<bool>(nullable: false),
        PasswordHash = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
        SecurityStamp = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
        ConcurrencyStamp = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
        PhoneNumber = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
        PhoneNumberConfirmed = table.Column<bool>(nullable: false),
        TwoFactorEnabled = table.Column<bool>(nullable: false),
        LockoutEnd = table.Column<DateTimeOffset>(nullable: true),
        LockoutEnabled = table.Column<bool>(nullable: false),
        AccessFailedCount = table.Column<int>(nullable: false),
        Discriminator = table.Column<string>(nullable: false),
        Grade = table.Column<int>(nullable: true),
        Subject = table.Column<string>(nullable: true)
    },
    constraints: table =>
    {
        table.PrimaryKey("PK_AspNetUsers", x => x.Id);
    });
```

Notice the last two properties are `Grade` and `Subject`.

It's similar to using a base class for all the `IdentitiyUser` which will derive from `IdentityUser` and include combination of all propeties and then just adding that one base class using `AddIdentity<TUser, TRole>` method.

Comment: what to do if you want to use asp net cores built in GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync for example but you haven't registered the token provider and cant use defaulttokenproviders for both classes?

Comment: The problem with merging all types of users into one, is that, given unique email validation was configured, different types of users cannot have the same email, while it should be allowed based on the business logic.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like has implemented in Active Directory, instead of creating a new table(entity) for each Access level group you can create only one where you will store Accees level groups `Admin  , Doctor , Patient`  , and so on. And include `IdenetityUser`  to any group ...
Of course, each group should have some roles.

For example - model:

```
    public class BaseGuidIdTable
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
}
    public class SecurityGroupRole: BaseGuidIdTable
{

    public string Role { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }

}
    public class SecurityRight: BaseGuidIdTable
{

    public string Right { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }
}

    public class SecurityGroupAccess: BaseGuidIdTable
{

    public Guid GroupId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(nameof(GroupId))]
    public SecurityGroupRole GroupRole { get; set; }

    public Guid RightId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(nameof(RightId))]
    public SecurityRight Right { get; set; }
}
```

Add some data :

```
            builder.Entity<SecurityGroupRole>().HasData(
            new SecurityGroupRole
            {
                Id = new Guid(OwnerGuidTxt),
                Role = "Doctor",
                Description = "Doctor"
            },
            new SecurityGroupRole
            {
                Id = new Guid(AdminGuidTxt),
                Role = "Admin",
                Description = "Admin"
            },
            new SecurityGroupRole
            {
                Id = new Guid(UserGuidTxt),
                Role = "Patient",
                Description = "Patient"
            }

        );
            builder.Entity<SecurityRight>().HasData(
            new SecurityRight
            {
                Id = new Guid(AddDeleteNewUsers),
                Right = "AddDeleteNewUsers",
                Description = "Add or delete Users"
            },
            new SecurityRight
            {
                Id = new Guid(PasswordChangeYourself),
                Right = "PasswordChangeYourself",
                Description = "Can password change by yourself"
            },
            new SecurityRight
            {
                Id = new Guid(ViewAll),
                Right = "ViewAll",
                Description = "Can view all objects"
            },
            new SecurityRight
            {
                Id = new Guid(CanChangeTags),
                Right = "CanChangeTags",
                Description = "Can change tags"
            } 
        );
                new SecurityGroupAccess {Id = new Guid("DD4C2CC3-65E2-4DD1-A620-723B5ADB8758"), GroupId = ownerGroupGuid, RightId = new Guid(AddDeleteNewUsers) },
            new SecurityGroupAccess { Id = new Guid("23CD8B4E-A572-4335-B1EF-2EF115E14947"), GroupId = ownerGroupGuid, RightId = new Guid(PasswordChangeYourself) },
            new SecurityGroupAccess { Id = new Guid("6A6A3A41-1103-46BD-B482-AB59903172D9"), GroupId = ownerGroupGuid, RightId = new Guid(ViewAll) },
            new SecurityGroupAccess { Id = new Guid("EB133F40-AB3B-4094-9AE7-EF6FD853F36B"), GroupId = ownerGroupGuid, RightId = new Guid(CanChangeTags) },

            new SecurityGroupAccess { Id = new Guid("29EE3EDA-08ED-46F1-9EF7-79A2D4021E86"), GroupId = adminGroupGuid, RightId = new Guid(PasswordChangeYourself) },
            new SecurityGroupAccess { Id = new Guid("59309220-F49B-4E30-B265-CB2ED71867B0"), GroupId = adminGroupGuid, RightId = new Guid(ViewAll) },
            new SecurityGroupAccess { Id = new Guid("F2F3FDF3-1ABC-46FF-BB62-E19B3F48E0AC"), GroupId = adminGroupGuid, RightId = new Guid(CanChangeTags) },

            new SecurityGroupAccess { Id = new Guid("7AC0F6A1-A585-40D6-B09B-DD6B86772935"), GroupId = userGroupGuid, RightId = new Guid(PasswordChangeYourself) }
```

So - in example we add 3 SecurityGroupRole `Admin  , Doctor , Patient`, and give each some right's, `Patient` can change password for himself for example ( excuse me - this is from other project - so naming can looking wrong)

Comment: I think the `IdentityRole` can do the work that you suggested.

Comment: @Muzib - yes - as described here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/customize-identity-model?view=aspnetcore-2.2#default-model-configuration