# asp.net core identity Multiple users from BaseApplicationUser

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-identity, ef-core-2.0, tph

I am using ASP.NET Core 2.2 Identity for my user management system.
I need to have several types of users ... for example, warehouse user and application user, which I create a base class that inherits from identity user class => `IdentityUser<long>`

```
public class BaseApplicationUser : IdentityUser<long>
{
    public string FirstName { set; get; }
    public string LastName { set; get; }
    ...
}
```

and warehouse user and store user inherit from `BaseApplicationUser` to create different users.

```
public class ApplicationUser : BaseApplicationUser
{
}
```

I want to have just one table for all of them => `AspNetUsers`
on `OnModelCreating` added this code :

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
{
    builder.Entity<ApplicationUser>();
    builder.Entity<WarehouseApplicationUser>();
}
```

and in DbSets in Context :

```
public DbSet<ApplicationRole> ApplicationRole { get; set; }
public DbSet<ApplicationUser> ApplicationUsers { get; set; }
public DbSet<WarehouseApplicationRole> WarehouseApplicationRole { get; set; }
public DbSet<WarehouseApplicationUser> WarehouseApplicationUsers { get; set; }
```

I need to create separate role classes for the users, like `ApplicationRole` and `WarehouseApplicationUsers`.

Whats is the problem?

1. How to create different users in asp.net core Identity? ( best
   way )
2. Another problem is that when I add a field to `ApplicationUser`, that field is successfully added to `AspNetUsers`, but when I add a field to `WarehouseApplicationUsers`, EF Core adds new tables named `WarehouseApplicationUsers` and `WarehouseApplicationRole` and `WarehouseApplicationUserRole` and then adds a field to the `WarehouseApplicationUsers` table... what is this!

**And finally, how can I inherit and build a hierarchy of different users? Thanks a lot**

Comment: Just don't use `IdentityUser` in your application code. Create something like an `ApplicationUser` that only has a foreign key to the IdentityUser in the database. Keep things apart. The application has nothing to do with `IdentityUser`'s concerns, and vv.

Answer (score 3):

Problem 1:
`How to create different users in asp.net core Identity ?`

ASP.NET Core provides a built-in method:`AddIdentityCore<TUser>`.

You can use it like this: `services.AddIdentityCore<ApplicationUser>();`

More details you can see this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64370175/how-to-add-multiple-identity-and-multiple-role-in-asp-net-core/64421573#64421573).

Problem 2:

Here is an example,you can compare to your code:

BaseApplicationUser:

```
 public class BaseApplicationUser: IdentityUser
{
    public string FirstName { set; get; }
    public string LastName { set; get; }
}
```

ApplicationUser:

```
 public class ApplicationUser : BaseApplicationUser
{
    public string Year { get; set; }
}
```

WarehouseApplicationUser:

```
public class WarehouseApplicationUser : BaseApplicationUser
{
     public string Age { get; set; }
}
```

ApplicationDbContext:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<BaseApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }
  
    public DbSet<ApplicationUser> ApplicationUsers { get; set; }
   
    public DbSet<WarehouseApplicationUser> WarehouseApplicationUsers { get; set; }
}
```

Migration result:
[image]

Answer (score -1):

NetCore **6.0.1** and EfCore 6.0.1 :

**DbContext :**

```
using Attendance.Server.Data.Entities;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace Attendance.Server.Data;
// this line in important :
public class AppDbContext : IdentityDbContext<User, Role, int, UserClaim, UserRole, UserLogin, RoleClaim, UserToken>
{
    public AppDbContext(DbContextOptions<AppDbContext> options) : base(options)
    {

    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        // AspNet Identity
        modelBuilder.Entity<User>(entity => { entity.ToTable("User"); });
        modelBuilder.Entity<Role>(entity => { entity.ToTable("Role"); });
        modelBuilder.Entity<UserRole>(entity => { entity.ToTable("UserRole"); });
        modelBuilder.Entity<RoleClaim>(entity => { entity.ToTable("RoleClaim"); });
        modelBuilder.Entity<UserClaim>(entity => { entity.ToTable("UserClaim"); });
        modelBuilder.Entity<UserLogin>(entity => { entity.ToTable("UserLogin"); });
        modelBuilder.Entity<UserToken>(entity => { entity.ToTable("UserToken"); });
    }
}
```

Create all **models** like this:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
namespace Attendance.Server.Data.Entities;
public class User : IdentityUser<int> { }
```

Do not forget install these **packages** on your web project:

- Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore
- Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer
- Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design

Add this line in your **program.cs** :

```
builder.Services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
```

your **appsettings.json** :

```
"Logging": {
"LogLevel": {
  "Default": "Information",
  "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
  }
},
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Attendance;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True"
  }
```

Finaly right click on your project (not solution) in Visual Studio and select **Open in Terminal** , then type these lines to migrate and create database:

```
dotnet ef migrations add createDB -o data/migrations
dotnet ef database update
```