# Application without identity but added later now secondary authentication is not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I have developed my first application using ASP.NET Core MVC 5.0.

There was a database already existing but I implemented full database in new program and now the issue was ASP.NET Core identity. So for identity I scaffolded as per instructions and finally implemented default identity authentication using email and pass.

```
services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = false)
                .AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
```

In `startup.cs` and after that I have a model with existing field i.e. cardno, phone and want to authenticate them on this. In PHP it was really very easy using `$_SESSION` variable. But now in here I want this to happen in ASP.NET any help will be appreciated.

```
services.AddIdentity<CnicUser, IdentityRole>().AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
```

This code I added for my custom authentication I got this error

> Application startup exception
> System.InvalidOperationException: Scheme already exists: Identity.Application
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationOptions.AddScheme(String
> name, Action`1 configureBuilder)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to add `identity service` twice in your `Startup.cs` which is incorrect. So the quick solution is you have to remove either of one which will remove the exception you are having with.

So remove `services.AddDefaultIdentity` which you have added earlier so it will work accordingly.

> **`Note:`** Deleting either of the addDefaultIdentities will work. You just can't have it in both locations in your case its creating the
> issue.

Comment: Farid I actually want to keep both the default identity procedure as well as want to authenticate other type of users VIA a model fields i.e cardno, phone

Comment: If you want to validate user with `cardno, phone` additional feild you can use model validation but if you want to add two kind of identity together I doubt you can do it. By the way what `CnicUser` contains?

Comment: Still if you want to use multiple  identity then you have to use `base class` then implement that base class on your new identity model. and then add that reference on `startup.cs` you can refer to this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64370175/how-to-add-multiple-identity-and-multiple-role-in-asp-net-core)

Comment: Farid CnicUser contains only inheritance from IdentityUser and yes i want to implement multiple identity but like default identity and other one is with two fields of tblemployee model.

Comment: Well, in that case you have to use [`identity extesion`](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/src/Identity/Extensions.Core/src/IdentityServiceCollectionExtensions.cs). Please have a look on [this thread as well](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47433269/multiple-identities-in-asp-net-core-2-0). Hope that would guide you accordingly

Comment: farid Really really thankful for your help but still it's not working in .net core 5.0

Comment: Are you getting any error?

Comment: yes actually let me show https://ctxt.io/2/AABgKhuREg

Comment: Farid I used services.AddIdentityCore<TblEmployee>().AddEntityFrameworkStores<Context>(); Then it asks me to extend from identity user but when i extend it gives me error that identity user columns are invalid but i don't want to add identityuser columns to my table

Comment: I have checked your error did you tried adding `identityuser`? additionally you could also follow the reference I referred to you.

Comment: Farid I tried using IdentityUserCore because identityuser after defaultidentity produces error