# Multiple Authentication provider asp.net core and associate them together

Tags: asp.net-core, authentication, cookies, azure-active-directory, facebook-authentication

I have a test application developed for my collage project.
with below table structure

```
tbl_UserMaster (userid int, username string, password string)
```

where I made users to authenticate with username and password.
And use application features.

Now, Our teacher assigned us task to authenticate using

```
MicrosoftAccount and Facebook
```

After much search and refer to various sources I am able to integrate both the login using asp.net core's AddAuthentication(options)

Now, we are given a new task to create a page that will associate SSO logins and database users. So, it would be upto user to login with SSO or Username and password.

And here I got stuck on how to associate both of them.
I have created table as below

```
tbl_UserMasterSSO (ssoID int, ProviderName string, NameIdentifier string, userid int(fk_tbl_UserMaster))
```

But, I don't have idea about how to, when user is already login with cookies then how to make them login with external provider and get NameIdentifier and associate with tbl_UserMaster's userid.

Requesting Experts to suggest an article or solution from where I can integrate the sample code to finish the task assigned.

Comment: Well, in that case you have to use [identity extesion](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/src/Identity/Extensions.Core/src/IdentityServiceCollectionExtensions.cs). Please have a look on [this thread as well](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47433269/multiple-identities-in-asp-net-core-2-0). Hope that would guide you accordingly. But note that you cannot have multipole identidy provider at the same time. It will lead you [authentication exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70417909/application-without-identity-but-added-later-now-secondary-authentication-is-not)

Comment: Is there any progress you were able to made on the context?

Comment: no sir.
Actually I need to implement solution like this stack over flow type website. already logged in used can attach their google/Github account with their existing username/password normal account.

Comment: what i mean to say is https://stackoverflow.com/users/login-add

Comment: In that case did you checked `github auth` steps of implementations? Please have a look [github official docs](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/about-authentication-to-github) same goes for `google auth` as well. Finally these option should be then displayed as your login option beside `user` and `password` base authentication.